# Capture high fps videos using new Camera API

Tags: android, video, camera

I'm trying to capture videos from camera at high frame rates. (60fps/120fps)
I'm testing on Nexus 5 device. From CameraCharacteristics, the available fps ranges are [15,15],[24, 24],[7, 30] and [30, 30]. So far I could save maximum 30fps videos. Is there a way to capture high fps videos using new camera APIs? Or is this a device hardware limitation?

Answer (score 1):

I think, Nexus 5 not being able to record 60 fps videos is mostly a driver limitation.
See this: https://github.com/PkmX/lcamera - "60/120 FPS Recording" section. It needs a custom driver to enable this functionality which basically breaks all other camera apps, so I suspect it's not really a clean solution. Officially only 30 fps is supported on Nexus 5.

Also I just posted a similar but more general question here: [Access high fps camera on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656138/access-high-fps-camera-on-android)